# Trying to display images from a specific folder in the Android hardware device

Tags: android

//posense is a directory in the Android hardware device and there are some pictures in the directory

```
    ImageView image1, image2;

    File imagedirectory;
    File[] imagepool;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        image1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        imagedirectory = new File("/posense"); 

        imagepool = imagedirectory.listFiles();

        image1.setImageResource(imagepool[1]); //this line is giving me an error

}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the error and is the file located on the SD Card or on the device storage?

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
image1.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imagepool[1]));
```

Documentation to be found here: [setImageURI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageURI%28android.net.Uri%29) and [fromFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#fromFile%28java.io.File%29).

Also, be aware that `imagepool[1]` is the second element in the array, not the first.

Answer (score 0):

Try these lines instead of `imagedirectory = new File("/posense");`:

```
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getName() + File.separatorChar + "posense";
    imagedirectory = new File(path);
    image1.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imagepool[1]));
```

Comment: Great to know that, please accept as answer if that helped you out.